# Bootloader doesn't change reset vector

Tags: bootloader, pic, mplab, pic18, xc8

I am using MPLAB IDE, MPLAB XC8 v6 Compiler, PIC18F25Q10. We are working with a bootloader project. While in the bootloader phase, it is expected to update the application and jump to a certain address (example code offset = 0x1000). However, we are having problems with reset vector, interrrupt vectors. We cannot move the reset vector and interrupt vectors to an address we want.

We did some research on the forums, Low and High Interrupt vector addresses can be changed with a command like "IVTBASE", but it is not used in the processor we use (PIC18F25Q10). A different way is to try the following line of code.

```
#define PROG_START  0x1000  
asm("PSECT reset_vector,class=CODE,delta=2,abs");  
asm("ORG  0x00"); 
asm("GOTO " \___mkstr(PROG_START)" + 0x00");
asm("PSECT HiVector,class=CODE,delta=2,abs");  
asm("ORG  0x08");  
asm("GOTO " \___mkstr(PROG_START)" + 0x08");  
asm("PSECT LoVector,class=CODE,delta=2,abs");  
asm("ORG  0x18"); 
asm("GOTO " \___mkstr(PROG_START)" + 0x18");
```

When we load this code into the processor via ICD4, it works correctly with the vector addresses correctly moved to address 0x1000. However, it does not work when we throw it through the bootloader application. Our hex output is as in the photo below.

[image]

We have a problem when we print this hex file with the bootloader application. For example, the reset vector address of the first 3 lines in the hex file is 0x0000, High Vector address = 0x0008, Low vector address = 0x0018 . When we print in this way, these vector addresses and bootloader application addresses conflict. We print to flash in the bootloader application.

How can we move the reset vectors through the bootloader application correctly? thank you.

Comment: Did you move the actual application (not the bootloader) with a code offset and then merged the application and bootloader file in the 'Loading' options?

Comment: One option that we done was to leave the ISR Vectors as is, load the Bootloader into the end of Flash (last few pages).  So, the PIC starts, JMP's to the Bootloader (located near the end of Flash), Bootloader ends and JMPs to the Application Start.  So, 0x000 -> ISR Vectors -> Application -> Bootloader -> End of Flash.  Hope that makes sense.